# Can I always split a finite dimensional vector space on any subspace with any bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form

Clearly the question as stated cannot be correct, as I can take the zero bilinear form, and take any nontrivial subspace. But I'm wondering where in the following proof I used nondegeneracy and symmetry, or please point out the mistake.

I'm given the following exercise: $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $B$, and $W$ a subspace such that $B|_W$ is nondegenerate. Then, $V\cong W\oplus W^\perp$. (Recall $W^\perp:=\{v\in V: B(v,w)=0, \forall w\in W\}$)

My proof (attempt?) is to do the following: Take an orthonormal basis $w_1,...,w_k$ for $W$. Consider the projection operator $p:V \to W$ given by $$p(v):=\sum_{i=1}^k B(v,w_i)w_i.$$
p is the identity on $W$ so it is surjective. By the first isomorphism theorem, we have a short exact sequence of vector spaces

$$0\to \ker p \to V\to W\to 0.$$

Since every SES of vector spaces splits, it suffices to show $\ker p= W^\perp$. If $v\in W^\perp$, then in particular for all $i$, $B(v,w_i)=0$. Thus,
$$p(v)=\sum B(v,w_i)w_i=0.$$

For the other direction, if $v\in \ker p$, then
$$0=\sum B(v,w_i)w_i\implies B(v,w_i)=0$$
since $w_i$ forms a basis for $W$. Then, for an arbitrary $w\in W$, we have $w=\sum_i a^i w_i$, so
$$B(v,w)=B(v,\sum a^iw_i)=\sum a^iB(v,w_i)=0.$$

So where did I use nondegeneracy of $B$ when restricted to $W$? And where did I use symmetry of $B$?.

Comment: "Take an orthonormal basis" is only possible if $B$ is nondegenerate. Also you should note that "orthonormality" is only well defined for positive-definite bilinear forms on vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. It could be that $B(v_{i}, v_{i} ) = -1$ for example. I would try reproving this without claiming a canonical form for $B|_{W} $ exists (That is, without claiming there is a basis of W for which $B(w_{i}, w_{j} ) = \pm \delta_{ij} $ ) - recall that to show $V \cong W \oplus W^{\bot} $ it's enough to show $dimW^{\bot} = codimW$.

Comment: Ah yes that's right. Thanks a bunch